# Very unusual fractions in Sympy, how do I solve this?

Tags: python, sympy

I get very weird fractions in sympy.
[image]

I have no clue why it is given me these unusual fractions

[image]

Comment: Try to be less lazy: CTRL+C and CTRL+V the code. Thank you very much

Comment: `Rational("0.1")` solves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
Rational("0.1")
# out: 1 / 10
Rational(0.1)
# out: 3602879701896397/36028797018963968
```

The second output happens because `0.1` is a number of type float, hence it is inherently inaccurate.

Comment: What about `nsimplify(0.1)`? [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#nsimplify) e.g. `nsimplify(sin(pi*0.1))` would be`-1/4 + sqrt(5)/4`

Answer (score 1):

sympy manual: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/explanation/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers

in short:

you type `Rational(0.1)`, then sympy has to test a float.

but `Rational("0.1")` works. str keep the number.

if you don't like this.

First convert it to sympy's type `Integer(1)/10`. Also works.